# Can't find the actual 'detail button' in a tableView's row

Tags: iphone, uitableview, accessorytype, accessoryview

When I click on my tableView's detail-button... I can manage to get the section number, the row number, and even the cell itself... but why is the actual "detail button" unobtainable?  (NSLog always displays "(null)" for the button.)

```
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    int section = indexPath.section;
    int row     = indexPath.row;

    UITableViewCell *aCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    UIButton *detailButton = (UIButton *)[aCell accessoryView];

    // Why is detailButton null?
    NSLog(@"accessory button tapped for row with index path %d x %d \n cell=(%@) \n button=(%@)", section, row, aCell, detailButton);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The accessory view is a UIView not a UIButton. Perhaps casting it to a button throws off the description method. Just a guess.

Comment: So how would we fix that?  Get the view... then get the button inside?  But how?

Comment: Not sure, I've never done it. I would start with examining the view hierarchy of the accessory view in the debugger to see what classes you are dealing with and in what order. Why do you need to examine the accessory view anyway? You already know what kind it is, that it has been hit and which row it is in. What else do you need to know?

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to access the button within the view. Perhaps something like

```
UIButton* detailBtn = [[UIButton alloc] init];
for (UIButton* detail in aCell.accessoryView.subviews)
{
     detailBtn = detail;
}
```

This assumes you only have your detail button in the accessory view, picks it out of the subview, and creates your references to it in detailBtn :)